# Get name of item in ListView

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to have name of item of ListView in **TextBlock**, i really need to have: When i click on item, in TextBlock will be name of this item. For example: When i (**in running**) application click on item in ListView, that name will be in that TextBlock. Also names of items in ListView are declaring in running application.Thank you !!! I have only this simple code:

```
private void lstViewOfUsers_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: It is UWP @TaW and Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want use the ItemClick event, you can use the [`ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventArgs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemClickEventArgs_ClickedItem) to get a reference to the clicked item.

If you add the ListViewItem by the XAML, you should be able to convert `ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem` to the root element in `ListViewItem`.

For example:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <ListViewItem>
        <TextBlock Name="Text1" Text="Text1"></TextBlock>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
        <TextBlock Name="Text2" Text="Text2"></TextBlock>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = e.ClickedItem as TextBlock;
    Debug.WriteLine(textBlock.Text);
}
```

If you bind the Collection to the `ListView.Source`, we should be able to  convert `ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem` to the object of the Collection.

For example:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> Items;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Items.Add("Text1");
    Items.Add("Text2");
    MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
}

private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var text = e.ClickedItem as string;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void lstViewOfUsers_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     myTextBlock.Text =((Control)sender).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to understand what exactly you are talking about, but it seems that what you may be looking for is:

```
private void lstViewOfUsers_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     myTextBlock.Text = e.DataContext as string;
}
```

If you aren't adding plain strings to the listview, but a custom object, you can do `myTextBlock.Text = (e.DataContext as myClass).myString`

Comment: e.DataContext is not existing :/

Comment: How are you adding data to the listview?

Answer (score 0):

First, please tell us more details about how you bind items to your ListView.
Assuming you have:

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItems}"
              ItemClick="MyListView_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Item">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And in the code behind it:

```
    private List<Item> MyItems;
    //Fill items of your need into this List
```

My approach is to create an identifier of each item you fill in the ListView. The identifier can be of any type you want. Here I use an enum. Remember to set the `Category` for every item in `MyItems` above:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ItemCategory Category { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ItemCategory
    {
        Type1,
        Type2
    }
```

And the main work in MyListView_ItemClick method:

```
     private void MenuItemsListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedItem = (Iteme)e.ClickedItem;
        switch (clickedItem.Category)
        {
            case ItemCategory.Type1:
            { 
                //Do your works here
                break;
            }

            case ItemCategory.Type2:
            { 
                //Do your works here
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```